# Pixel Intensity in opencv#

Tags: opencv

I am a beginner in both Image Processing and Opencv. I am trying to find out the individual pixel intensities of an image, using OPENCV#. There is assistance here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html?highlight=pixel%20intensity for the same issue. But I am not sure how to use it in OPENCV#. 
I know this is a very basic query. Please try to help out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Pixel intensity is the same thing as that pixel's grayscale value. To get a grayscale (pixel intensity) version of an BGR image you can do this:

```
cv::cvtColor(bgr_mat,gray_mat,CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Now the 3 channel BGR image has been converted to a 1 channel GRAYSCALE image. To find the intensity of pixel (x,y) in the gray image you can do this:

```
//NOTE: in OpenCV pixels are accessed in (row,col) format
int intensity = (int)gray_mat.at<uchar>(y,x);
```

Since each grayscale pixel is stored as uchar, the value of `intensity` will range from (0-255) where 255 is maximum intensity (seen as a completely white pixel).

Comment: Shouldn't the conversion in your first line of code use CV_BGR2GRAY instead, since OpenCV typically uses BGR versus RGB?

Comment: It doesnt matter what order the pixels are in, bgr and rgb will have the same grayscale result and for simplicity since the user was new and using imported images I explained in rgb format.

Comment: But the red, green, and blue are not converted to grey the same way.  Typically, r*0.299, g*0.587, and b*0.114.  With the code you have, green is fine, but red and blue have been switched which will give you the "wrong" intensity.

Comment: Only reason I bring this up is because I've run into this before.  See:  https://answers.opencv.org/question/196656/how-are-rgb-images-converted-to-greyscale/

Answer (score 1):

in emgu cv, you can do it like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/171302/does-anybod-know-how-to-access-pixel-data).

```
//Color
//Red 
byte Red_val = My_Image.Data[y,x,0];
//Green 
byte Green_val = My_Image.Data[y,x,1];
//Blue 
byte Blue_val = My_Image.Data[y,x,2];
```

---

```
//Greyscale
byte Gray_val = My_Image.Data[y,x,0];
```